# How to get set the text of select box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i was setting the drop down value by typing into the text box. Problem is my  dropdown values are different from the text of the options in the dropdown. So i have to type the value of each option into text to get the correct text in dropdown. How to select the text by putting text in the text box.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#txt_scheme").keyup(function(){
     $("#scheme").val($("#txt_scheme").val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">Scheme**</label>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
   <select class="form-control" name="scheme" id="scheme">
      <?php
         for ($column = 'A'; $column <= $lastcol; $column++) {
           echo '<option value="' . $column . '">' . $worksheet->getCell($column . '1')->getValue() . '</option>';
         }
      ?>
   </select>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txt_scheme" name="txt_scheme" placeholder="Or Type here">
   </div>
</div>
```

My dropdown options are

```
QC code 
Analyte 
Assay Value 
Assigned Value  
STANDARDDEVIATION   
ACCEPTABLEMIN   
ACCEPTABLEMAX   
Sample ID   
Date
```

and there values are in alphabets like QC Code have A value.

So if i type `QC code` in the text it should select `QC code` from the dropdown. right now i m getting it by typing `A`

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `filter` function in order to obtain `value` of option with `txt_scheme` text:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txt_scheme").keyup(function(){
        var valueFromText=$("#scheme option").filter(function(i,option){
            return $(option).text()==$("#txt_scheme").val();
        }).val();
        $("#scheme").val(valueFromText);
    });
});
```

```js
$("#txt_scheme").keyup(function(){
        var valueFromText=$("#scheme option").filter(function(i,option){
            return $(option).text().toLowerCase()==$("#txt_scheme").val().toLowerCase();
        }).val();
        $("#scheme").val(valueFromText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="scheme">
   <option value="A">QC code</option> 
  <option value="B">Analyte</option>
  <option value="C">Assay Value </option>
  <option value="D">Assigned Value </option>
  <option value="E">STANDARDDEVIATION</option>
  <option value="F">ACCEPTABLEMIN</option>
  <option value="G">ACCEPTABLEMAX</option>
  <option value="H">Sample ID</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txt_scheme"/>
```

Comment: Beautifully worked! just one thing that is it possible that i can write into lower case. I have to correct type all the text.?

Comment: @adeel, yes , it is possible using `toLowerString()` method. I updated my answer.

Comment: @ Alexandru-Ionut Mihai very well done! thankx for providing me a quick solution was searching for 5 hours but i was not getting proper answer. may be was not searching through proper keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to grab the select option by its text value, and then set its `selected` attribute to true:

```
var textValue = $("#txt_scheme").val();
$("select option:contains("+textValue+")").attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: sorry i did not get your answer. can you plz tel me briefly